# How can I distinct between different linetypes when using geom_smooth and facet_grid (R-Studio / ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, scatter-plot, facet-grid

I'm plotting some data in R-Studio and been using ggplot2. At the moment I'm plotting scatterplots with regression lines. However not all of my linear models in these scatterplots are statistically significant.
So I basically want to tell R and ggplot, that whenever my model is not significant it should use "11" as a linetype in color "red". However if the model is significant just use color "green4".

Basically like this:

```
geom_smooth(linetype= "11", formula= y~x, method = lm, color="indianred2") #for non-significant results
```

and

```
geom_smooth(formula= y~x, method = lm, color="green4") #for significant results.
```

How can I implement it in my code?

Thanks in advance and greeting from Berlin, Germany!

Here is my code and a picture of my scatterplot. (Please note, that I'm not totally done with the aesthetics yet)

```
rich <- ggplot(Umw_Daten, aes(x=Jahr_int, y=Richness)) + geom_point(size=2) +
  facet_grid(Orig_Biot~., scales = "free", space="free") +
  geom_smooth(formula= y~x, method = lm)+
  theme_light()+
  stat_cor(aes(label = paste(..rr.label..)), r.accuracy = 0.01)+
  stat_cor(aes(label = paste( ..p.label..)),method = "pearson", p.accuracy = 0.001)
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest you do your regression yourself (not within ggplot/geom_smooth), add a variable to the frames indicating significance, then use `geom_line(aes(..., linetype=my_significance)) + scale_linetype_manual(values=c("signif"="solid","insignif"="11"))` (and same for `scale_color_manual`).

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function on the data you are using and pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg